# Updating Variable Values within UDF Pyspark

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, pyspark

I want to have a udf function that goes through column "Values", and checks to see if the next value is 50% or more of the current row value. If it is within 50% percent then I want to include the value "yes" if it isn't then I do not want to include the value. If the value drops too quickly between the last value and the next value then it should not be included, but if it gradually drops and not by more than 50% compared to the last included value then it's alright. 
This is why .1 for id 5 was not included but .1 for id 9 was included because it followed a value that gradually dropped from .4 by no more than 50%. I was thinking about having a variable in the udf to keep track of the last acceptable value, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
rows = sc.parallelize([[1, .9, 'yes'], [2, .7, 'yes'], [3, .4, 'yes'], [4, .15, 'no'], [5, .1, 'no'], [7, .3, 'yes'], [8, .2, 'yes'], [9, .1, 'yes']])

rows_df = rows.toDF(["ID",  'Values', 'Include'])

#preview data
rows_df.show()

#show data schema
rows_df.printSchema()

+---+------+-------+
| ID|Values|Include|
+---+------+-------+
|  1|   0.9|    yes|
|  2|   0.7|    yes|
|  3|   0.4|    yes|
|  4|  0.15|     no|
|  5|   0.1|     no|
|  7|   0.3|    yes|
|  8|   0.2|    yes|
|  9|   0.1|    yes|
+---+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you don't have to use UDF (in fact I don't think it would be possible), you can instead use various functions that work over a window, e.g. `lag`.

I have to admit I don't fully understand your requirement (why 5. should be 'no'?), but between `lag`, `lead` and `last` you should be able to implement it. You can read more about them in [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last). A sample that does logic based on previous value:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, when, lit

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("Id")

withPrevious = rows_df.withColumn("prevVal", lag(rows_df["Values"]).over(windowSpec))

withPrevious.withColumn("Include2", 
                        when(col("prevVal").isNull(), "yes")\
                        .when(col("Values") >= 0.5 * col("prevVal"), lit("yes"))\
                        .otherwise("no"))\
    .show()
```

```
+---+------+-------+-------+--------+
| ID|Values|Include|prevVal|Include2|
+---+------+-------+-------+--------+
|  1|   0.9|    yes|   null|     yes|
|  2|   0.7|    yes|    0.9|     yes|
|  3|   0.4|    yes|    0.7|     yes|
|  4|  0.15|     no|    0.4|      no|
|  5|   0.1|     no|   0.15|     yes|
|  7|   0.3|    yes|    0.1|     yes|
|  8|   0.2|    yes|    0.3|     yes|
|  9|   0.1|    yes|    0.2|     yes|
+---+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I want row id 5 to be no but row 9 to be yes, i'm thinking that i will need to iterate through the row values using a for loop if a udf is not possible.

Comment: Could you explain step by step how you calculate the 'no' for 5?

Comment: at id1, the value is .9 and id 2 is yes because .7 is less than 50 percent drop, last accepted value now to compare is .7, so id3 is a yes, last accepted value is now .4 and the next two ids 4-5 are no because they are more than 50% drop of .4 then we get to id 7 with .3 which is a yes and the new accepted value becomes .3 and the next id is also a yes and the new a.v become .2 and since .1 for id 9 does not drop more than 50% it is accepted here